# Back button and query strings in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I'm using Create React App for a simple application that builds a list of cards from an API fetch and searches them using a form. But here are two quirks:

1. The form pushes new URLs to the browser's history using `history.push` (React Router), i.e. `?=searchquery`
2. When visited for the first time, these links' query strings are used to initiate the given search

The problem is when I use the browser's back button. In Chrome and Safari, nothing really happens. The url changes, but the App doesn't update.

This is what I have in my `App.js`

```
export default function App() {

    // Browser stuff we need to access 
    const { search } = useLocation()
    const values = new URLSearchParams(search)
    const history = useHistory();

    // Pass values to form input, define Value and set Searching
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState(values.get("q") ? values.get("q") : "")
    const [inputKey, setInputKey] = useState(values.get("q") ? values.get("q") : "")
    const [searching, setSearching] = useState(true)
    
    // Fetch related stuff
    const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true)
    const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0)
    const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([])
    const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_KEY
    const fetchurl = `redacted`

    const getData = useCallback(
      () => {
        fetch(fetchurl).then(resp => resp.json()).then(resp => {
          if (offset === 0) {
            setMarkers(resp.rows)
          }
          else {
            setMarkers(markers => [...markers, ...resp.rows])
          }
          if (resp.total_rows !== 50) {
            setHasMore(false)
          }
          setSearching(false)
        })
      },
      [fetchurl, offset],
    );

    useEffect(() => {
      getData()
      console.log("ran this")
    }, [getData])

return (
      
       ...

      )
}
```